# How do I create a link that redirects to a destination after completing an action?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to create login/logout options for menus that are parts of groups on my page. The thing is I want each menu to have that login/logout select redirect the user to the group page, not the user profiles. How would I go about setting this up in the path setting of the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try appending a **?destination=/path/to/destination** in the URL of your menu.

For example when setting up the menu for logout you can type:

> [yoursitehere]/user/logout?destination=node/23

Do the same for login menu path.

Comment: THis seems preferably to installing a new module for this sort of thing, unless that module has features that would trump something like this

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module.  From the project page:

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [Login Toboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) which among other things allows:

- Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
- Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.

It also has over 80K installs.  Great module.